# Why aren't these variables initialized correctly in my constructor?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and when I was working on a project, I couldn't understand why it wasn'† working. So I tested my first file, and my problem seems to be here.

This is mye code:

```
class Example {
  private int memory;
  private int processors;

  public Example(int memory, int processors) {
    memory = memory;
    processors = processors;
  }


  public int getProcessors() {
    return processors;
  }


  public boolean enoughMemory(int memorylimit) {
    if (memorylimit <= memory) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }


}
```

And this is my test-file:

```
public class TestExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   Example example = new Example(16, 2);

    int a = example.getProcessors();
    boolean b = example.enoughMemory(12);

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);

  }
}
```

So, what I want, and what I expect as output is:

```
2
true
```

But, what I get is:

```
0
false
```

I dont't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help me!

Comment: Remember to use the "this" keyword when the same variable names are used. Otherwise, the program doesn't know which "memory" or "processor" variables you're referring to.

Comment: create set method for ``memory`` and ``processors ``, in ``main`` method, ``example.setMemory(xxx)`` and ``example.setProcessors(xxx)``

Comment: If its unclear from the duplicate, you would need to add in `this.memory = memory;`
`this.processor = processor`

Comment: One way to catch this is to make the field variables final, i.e. `private final int memory;` and `private final int processors;`.  This way, the compiler won't allow you forget to initialize the variables by forgetting `this.` references.  As a bonus, the variables will be immutable, which will prevent all kinds of potential runtime bugs down the road.

Comment: @DonaldWu set methods aren't needed here. The constructor already serves that purpose.